# Execute JS on page load without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

So I know that if you use jQuery you can use `$(document).load(function(){});` so that any code you write into the function gets executed after the whole page has loaded, but is there a way of doing something similar if you don't use jQuery and just use JS?

For example...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var box = document.getElementById('box');
            alert(box);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#999; 
margin:20px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I use this method the alert just says `null`. So is there a way of making the js code run once the page has loaded?

Comment: Actually, when using jQuery, please **do not** use `$(document).load(function(){...});`

Comment: This question might have an answer that you need [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        //do stuff here
    };
</script>
```

This way you don't have to use any onload tags in your html.

Comment: I like you way, 1 answer coming up when it lets me.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to simply put your script at the end of the document, typically just before the closing body tag:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="box" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:#999; margin:20px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    alert(box);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so get the js to find the element #box the js tags have to go within the body section rather than within the head tag?

Comment: @user1563944 - more specifically, the javascript has to come after the element you're trying to access, otherwise the element does'nt exist when the javascript executes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variety of methods to accomplish this.

The simplest, easiest method would be to simply add the script tag at the end of your body tag:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Example </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Do stuff here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The way jQuery does it is something similar to:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

I usually just do it the second way, just in case.

To ensure cross-browser compatibility, crawl through the source of jQuery and find what they use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use onload in your body tag.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSomething() {
         //your code here
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="doSomething()">
```